# How to check and reset the boolean value of many options one times?

Tags: programming, options, core-language

I defined a function which owns many options. In addtion, these options have a common characteristic. Namely, only accepting boolean value `True` or `False`. Here is a screenshot as below:

[image]

Obviously, I check the values of these options step-by-step. Now I want to check them with a auxiliary function called `checkBoolValues[]`.

***Update***: thanks for [jkuczm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/14303/jkuczm) and [Sjoerd C.deVries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/57/sjoerd-c-de-vries), I add the `HoldRest` attribute to a `Function[]` body

```
General::invbool = 
  "Value of option `1` \[Rule] `2` should be a valid boolean value of True or False.";

checkBoolValues[func_, optsNameValue_List] :=
 Scan[
  Function[{optName, optValue},
    If[! MemberQ[{True, False}, optValue], 
     Message[func::invbool, optName, optValue];
     optValue = False
    ], 
  HoldRest] @@ # &, 
  optsNameValue
 ]
```

Following is the code boloc that used in my function.

```
Options[BSplineCurveInterpolate] = 
 {OriginPoints -> False, ControlPoints -> False, 
  SplineClosed -> False, TangentVector -> False};

BSplineCurveInterpolate[
  pts_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{op, cp, tv, sc},
  (*achieve the value of options*)
  op = OptionValue[OriginPoints];
  cp = OptionValue[ControlPoints];
  tv = OptionValue[TangentVector];
  sc = OptionValue[SplineClosed];
  (*check the values of options*)
  checkBoolValues[
   BSplineCurveInterpolate, 
   {{OriginPoints, op}, {ControlPoints, cp}, 
    {TangentVector, tv}, {SplineClosed, sc}}
  ];
  (*return the values of options*)
  {op, cp, tv, sc}
 ]
```

However, the test case shows that the `checkBoolValues[]` cannot achieve the effect like step-by-step.

```
BSplineCurveInterpolate[
  {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 
  OriginPoints -> aaa, 
  ControlPoints -> bbb, 
  SplineClosed -> True, 
  TangentVector -> False]
```

[image]

Here, I discovered that the `Head` of `aaa` and `bbb` are `Symbol`, owing to the `HoldRest` attribute of `Function[]` body, `aaa` and `bbb` will be assigned to a value `False`, so when I executed the `BSplineCurveInterpolate[...]` in the sceond time, there is no warning information occurs.

However, when the option value is a number, *Mathematica* will throw the following `Set::setraw` info.

```
BSplineCurveInterpolate[
  {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 
  OriginPoints -> 11, 
  ControlPoints -> 22, 
  SplineClosed -> True, TangentVector -> False]
```

[image]

So I would like to know how to refactor the auxiliary function `checkBoolValues[]`.

Comment: Did you run posted code on clean kernel? I do get error messages when running your code and get desired output, but additionally I get `StringForm::sfr` messages since you only pass one message argument to `BSplineCurveInterpolate::invbool` while it expects 2. Also `False` values are really assigned to `aaa` and `bbb` symbols and not local `op` and `cp` symbols. You've surely seen [Attempting to make an assignment to the argument of a function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18737/14303)? It applies to your `checkBoolValues` and to pure function used inside it in `Scan`.

Comment: Are you sure you may pass the function name in a variable func to Message? I can imagine that Message actually is looking for a definition of func itself. Additionally, the message string has two slots, yet you provide a single argument only.

Comment: There's already a built-in message to report desired error: `General::opttf`.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Thanks, I made a mistake. In addition, did you mean the `Message[]`will look for the defintion of `func::invbol` rather than `BSplineCurveInterpolate::invbol`?

Comment: @jkuczm Thanks :) I have updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Why your function doesn't work

Your `checkBoolValues` does not hold any of its arguments, so when you pass to it, inside `BSplineCurveInterpolate`, for example `op` local symbol, it gets evaluated. Inside body of `checkBoolValues` you really use value of this symbol not the symbol itself.

This behavior was discussed many times on this site, in particular in [Attempting to make an assignment to the argument of a function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18737/14303) answer to [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/14303) question.

That's why in first evaluation of:

```
BSplineCurveInterpolate[
  {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 
  OriginPoints -> aaa, 
  ControlPoints -> bbb, 
  SplineClosed -> True, TangentVector -> False]
```

in which you get desired messages and output, you also get undesired side effect. `False` values that, as I think, you intended to assign to local symbols `op` and `cp`, are really assigned to global `aaa` and `bbb` symbols that where passed as options.

That's why, in second usage of `BSplineCurveInterpolate` with `aaa` and `bbb` as option values, there are no errors, related to them, reported, because those symbols evaluate to `False` which is an acceptable value.

---

## Overriding `OptionValue`

If you want to make sure that values of certain `BSplineCurveInterpolate` options are tested wherever they are accessed, you can override `OptionValue` by setting appropriate `UpValues` on `BSplineCurveInterpolate`.

Let's define a helper function that overrides `OptionValue` for given function and for options matching given pattern. Overriden `OptionValue` will extract value of given option, test it using given `testFunc` function, and if test returns `False` it'll return result of given `defaultFunc` called with option name and option value as arguments.

```
ClearAll[$useOverriddenOptionValue, setOptionValueTest]
$useOverriddenOptionValue = True;
SetAttributes[setOptionValueTest, HoldFirst]
setOptionValueTest[f_Symbol, optNamePatt_, testFunc_, defaultFunc_] := (
    f /: OptionValue[f, opts_ | PatternSequence[], optNames_List] /;
            $useOverriddenOptionValue :=
        OptionValue[f, opts, #] & /@ optNames;
    f /: ov : OptionValue[f, opts_ | PatternSequence[], optName : optNamePatt] /;
            $useOverriddenOptionValue :=
        If[TrueQ@testFunc[#], #, defaultFunc[optName, #]] &@
            Block[{$useOverriddenOptionValue = False}, ov]
)
```

Now let's define options for `BSplineCurveInterpolate`, and set appropriate tests for their values.

```
ClearAll[BSplineCurveInterpolate]
Options[BSplineCurveInterpolate] = {
    OriginPoints -> False, ControlPoints -> False,
    SplineClosed -> False, TangentVector -> False
};
setOptionValueTest[BSplineCurveInterpolate,
    OriginPoints | ControlPoints | TangentVector | SplineClosed,
    MatchQ[True | False],
    (Message[BSplineCurveInterpolate::opttf, #1, #2]; False) &
]
```

Now whole option value testing will be performed in ordinary call of `OptionValue`, so we just use it **without any additional code** (except when using fourth argument of `OptionValue` since then returned value can be arbitrary and defined test function might be inappropriate):

```
BSplineCurveInterpolate[pts : {{_, _} ..} | {{_, _, _} ..}, OptionsPattern[]] :=
    Module[{n, op, cp, ss, tv, sc},
        {op, cp, tv, sc} = OptionValue[
            {OriginPoints, ControlPoints, TangentVector, SplineClosed}
        ];
        (*return the values of options*)
        {op, cp, tv, sc}
    ]
```

Now `BSplineCurveInterpolate` gives desired results:

```
Off[General::stop]
ClearAll[aaa, bbb, Trtttue]
BSplineCurveInterpolate[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, OriginPoints -> aaa, 
    ControlPoints -> bbb, SplineClosed -> True, TangentVector -> False]
BSplineCurveInterpolate[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, OriginPoints -> aaa, 
    ControlPoints -> bbb, SplineClosed -> Trtttue, TangentVector -> False]
BSplineCurveInterpolate[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, OriginPoints -> aaa, 
    ControlPoints -> bbb, SplineClosed -> Trtttue, TangentVector -> 222]
On[General::stop]
```

[image: BSplineCurveInterpolate results]

---

## (Old answer) Refactoring `checkBoolValues`

Instead of playing with holding arguments and assigning `False` to local symbols inside `checkBoolValues`, I'd use a function that simply returns list of desired option values and prints messages when appropriate.

We start with simple helper function checking option value for `True` or `False`, returning value if it's correct. Printing message and returning `False` if value is incorrect. I'm using built-in `General::opttf` instead of a custom message.

```
ClearAll[checkBoolOption]
checkBoolOption[_][_, val : True | False] := val
checkBoolOption[func_][name_, val_] := (
    Message[func::opttf, name, val];
    False
)
```

Now a function that works like second and third documented usage of built-in [`OptionValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OptionValue.html), but, in addition to returning option values, it checks whether they are booleans.

```
ClearAll[boolOptionValue]
boolOptionValue[func_, opts:{OptionsPattern[]}:{}, optName : _Symbol | _String] :=
    checkBoolOption[func][optName, OptionValue[func, opts, optName]]
boolOptionValue[func_, opts:{OptionsPattern[]}:{}, optNames:{(_Symbol | _String)...}] :=
    MapThread[
        checkBoolOption[func],
        {optNames, OptionValue[func, opts, optNames]}
    ]
```

Example usage in `BSplineCurveInterpolate`:

```
ClearAll[BSplineCurveInterpolate]
Options[BSplineCurveInterpolate] = {
    OriginPoints -> False, ControlPoints -> False,
    SplineClosed -> False, TangentVector -> False
};

BSplineCurveInterpolate[pts : {{_, _} ..} | {{_, _, _} ..}, opts:OptionsPattern[]] :=
    Module[{n, op, cp, ss, tv, sc},
        (*check and assign values of options*)
        {op, cp, tv, sc} = 
            boolOptionValue[BSplineCurveInterpolate, {opts},
                {OriginPoints, ControlPoints, TangentVector, SplineClosed}
            ];
        (*return the values of options*)
        {op, cp, tv, sc}
    ]
```

Now `BSplineCurveInterpolate` gives desired results:

```
Off[General::stop]
ClearAll[aaa, bbb, Trtttue]
BSplineCurveInterpolate[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, OriginPoints -> aaa, 
    ControlPoints -> bbb, SplineClosed -> True, TangentVector -> False]
BSplineCurveInterpolate[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, OriginPoints -> aaa, 
    ControlPoints -> bbb, SplineClosed -> Trtttue, TangentVector -> False]
BSplineCurveInterpolate[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, OriginPoints -> aaa, 
    ControlPoints -> bbb, SplineClosed -> Trtttue, TangentVector -> 222]
On[General::stop]
```

[image: BSplineCurveInterpolate results]

Comment: Like the helper function `checkBoolOption[]` and it is the firtst time for me to see the usage of `OptionValue[func, {opts}, optName]`. THX:)

Comment: @ShutaoTANG I'm glad you like it. As to `OptionValue[func, opts, optName]`, variant with single option name is documented, passing list of option names is not, but I think I've seen it couple of times on this site.